# Is the following sentence grammatically correct and in a correct form?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

> When dinner time, we always go through the fact that what to eat..

assume that we're always arguing about what food to eat! So according to this, Is the sentence above in a correct form or not?

Comment: Welcome! Proofreading requests, that don't ask about a specific problem, are not one of the [topics covered here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But there are multiple problems with the sentence. A working version might be "When **it's** dinner time, we always [go through an argument about] what to eat." There are various different phrases that could also go in place of "go through an argument about," like "go over what to eat," or simply "argue about what to eat."

Comment: You really need to check your basic grammar.

Comment: Please note that in English (unlike German, for example) we do not habitually use the ! symbol to end a sentence in the imperative mood. In fact, using it that way can suggest impatience or anger, and that is probably not your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When dinner time

is not correct in standard English (at least AmE or BrE), it should be something like "at dinner time" or "when it is dinner time.

> we always go through the fact that

is also not correct. One does not go **through** a fact. Also the phrase "the fact that", while often used, is IME commonly a sign of poor writing. a;so "what to eat" is not a fact, and so does not fit after "the fact that".

To indicate a recurring argument, one might say "we always argue about what to est" or "we always have an argument about what to eat" or even 'every day we have the same argument about what to eat. Or, less strongly, "we always debate [or "discuss"] what to eat".